# The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server

Tags: c#

I need to use talk talk soap service in dot net core and i am not able to get any output i have done code according to document but this is giving 
"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="L7SSGBasicRealm"'." error after run the project. i think this is related to header i need to pass header but i don't know how can we pass it but i don't have any url of this service i have only wsdl file. i consumed it and now using it , i think i need to pass credentials in header but i am not able to pass header with using wsdl file.

```
        try
        {
            string[] accessCircuit = new string[9];
            accessCircuit[0] = "MPF";
            accessCircuit[1] = "SMPF";
            accessCircuit[2] = "Offnet";
            accessCircuit[3] = "EoFTTC";
            accessCircuit[4] = "EFM";
            accessCircuit[5] = "EAD";
            accessCircuit[6] = "FTTC";
            accessCircuit[7] = "All";
            accessCircuit[8] = "FTTP";

            NominatedCLIRequest nominatedCLIRequest = new NominatedCLIRequest();
            nominatedCLIRequest.CLI = "SIN227"; // "1471"
            nominatedCLIRequest.Retain = RetainEnum.No;

            PostcodeAvailabilityRequest postcodeAvailabilityRequest = new PostcodeAvailabilityRequest();
            postcodeAvailabilityRequest.Postcode = "WC2N 5DU";
            postcodeAvailabilityRequest.PerformMPFACCheck = PerformMPFACCheckEnum.Yes;

            GALKAvailabilityRequest gALKAvailabilityRequest = new GALKAvailabilityRequest();
            gALKAvailabilityRequest.GoldAddressKey = "A00021306338";

            NonGALKAvailabilityRequest nonGALKAvailabilityRequest = new NonGALKAvailabilityRequest();
            nonGALKAvailabilityRequest.NonGoldAddressKey = "A000rte";

            TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest telephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest = new TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest();
            telephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest.ProxyCLI = true;

            AddressAvailabilityRequest addressAvailabilityRequest = new AddressAvailabilityRequest();
            addressAvailabilityRequest.Postcode = "WC2N 5DU";

            UPRNAvailabilityRequest uPRNAvailabilityRequest = new UPRNAvailabilityRequest();
            uPRNAvailabilityRequest.UPRN = 5678;

            AvailabilityRequest availabilityRequest = new AvailabilityRequest();
            availabilityRequest.PostcodeAvailabilityRequest = postcodeAvailabilityRequest;
            availabilityRequest.GALKAvailabilityRequest = gALKAvailabilityRequest;
            availabilityRequest.NonGALKAvailabilityRequest = nonGALKAvailabilityRequest;
            availabilityRequest.TelephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest = telephoneNumberAvailabilityRequest;
            availabilityRequest.AddressAvailabilityRequest = addressAvailabilityRequest;
            availabilityRequest.UPRNAvailabilityRequest = uPRNAvailabilityRequest;

            NetworkProductAvailabilityRequest networkProductAvailabilityRequest = new NetworkProductAvailabilityRequest();
            networkProductAvailabilityRequest.AccessCircuit = accessCircuit;
            networkProductAvailabilityRequest.NominatedCLIRequestDetails = nominatedCLIRequest;
            networkProductAvailabilityRequest.UserConsent = UserConsent.No;
            networkProductAvailabilityRequest.RequestDetails = availabilityRequest;

            NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerServiceClient networkProductAvailabilityCheckerServiceClient = new NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerServiceClient() ;
            var availabilityDetails = await networkProductAvailabilityCheckerServiceClient.GetAvailabilityAsync(networkProductAvailabilityRequest);

            return availabilityDetails;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

This is the code i created request for service according to document but don't know that how can authenticate it

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with the TalkTalk API when doing 
NetworkProductAvailabilityRequests; I fixed the issue by using this code:

```
 using (var availabilityService = new NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerServiceClient())
            {
                availabilityService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "your username here";
                availabilityService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "your password here";

                var availabilityRequest = new NetworkProductAvailabilityRequest
                {

                    UserConsent = UserConsent.Yes,
                    AccessCircuit = new[] { "EAD" },
                    RequestDetails = new PostcodeAvailabilityRequest
                    {
                        Postcode = input
                    }
                };
             }
```

However when using this I came across a 401 Unauthorised Issue as I was not passing through the AgentID in my request, to fix this it looks like you will have to custom build a HTTP request with custom headers to get the response back and parse that yourself.